# Select query - To select parent permissions

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help in writing up a query - please see the tables structure below

**Category**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `catid` varchar(170) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(170) NOT NULL,
  `parent_catid` varchar(170) NOT NULL,
  `inherit_parent_perms` enum ('Y', 'N') NOT NULL,
  KEY `idx_wss` (`catid`)
);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES('1', 'Fruits', '0', 'N');
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES('2', 'Apples', '1', 'N');
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES('3', 'Furniture', '0', 'N');
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES('4', 'Toys', '0', 'N');
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES('5', 'Gifts', '4', 'Y');
```

and a permissions table

**Permissions**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `permissions` (
  `catid` varchar(170) NOT NULL,
  `permission_object` enum ('seller', 'buyer') NOT NULL,
  `permission_object_id` varchar(170) NOT NULL,
  KEY `idx_wss` (`catid`)
);


INSERT INTO `permissions` VALUES('1', 'seller', '100'); -- Here category 1 is accessible to 'seller' object with ID 100
INSERT INTO `permissions` VALUES('1', 'buyer', '300');  -- Here category 1 is accessible to 'buyer' object with ID 300

INSERT INTO `permissions` VALUES('2', 'buyer', '200');  -- Here category 2 is accessible to 'buyer' object with ID 200

INSERT INTO `permissions` VALUES('3', 'buyer', 'all');  -- Here category 3 is accessible to all 'buyer' objects
INSERT INTO `permissions` VALUES('3', 'seller', 'all'); -- Here category 3 is accessible to all 'seller' objects
```

As you can see how category table is referenced in permissions table and a category can be accessed by an object type with an id or by all object types when object id is set as 'all'

This is the query I have got so far

```sql
SELECT id, name, p. *
FROM `catalogue` c
LEFT JOIN permissions p ON p.cat = c.catid
AND (
        (
            (
                p.permission_object_id = 'all'
                OR p.permission_object_id = '100'
            )
                AND p.permission_object = 'seller'
        )
        OR 
        (
            (
                p.permission_object_id = 'all'
                OR p.permission_object_id = '100'
            )
                AND p.permission_object = 'buyer'
        )
    )
WHERE catid = 3
```

**Questions**

Above query kind of works - e.g. if category 3 is accessible to buyer ID 100 - it would show the content under it. If this category was allowed to buyer ID 'all' then any buyer can see this category.

But the problem is when I have sub-categories. So if Category 3 is accessible by 'all' and and then I add two sub-categories 4 and 5 (under category 3) and tell it to inherit permissions from parent for 4 and sub-category 5 accessible by 'seller' ID 200 only - then I don't understand what to do here.

- Do I need to copy all the parent permissions and insert as new rows (obviously with new category ID) when marked as inherit parent permissions .... OR .... I could somehow use the same query with some changes in it (which I don't know how to).
- any other changes/suggestions to the above would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will only handle one level of sub-categorisation i.e. it will not work if you added sub-categories to categories 4 & 5.

It should get you started off though if I have understood your question correctly:

```
-- Assuming category 5 is a sub-category of category 3 and has inherit_parent_perms='Y'

select *
from
(
-- select permisssions for this category
SELECT c.catid, c.name, p.permission_object,p.permission_object_id
FROM `category` c
LEFT JOIN `permissions` p ON p.catid = c.catid
where c.catid = 5
union
-- select permissions from parent category if it exists
SELECT c.catid, c.name, p.permission_object,p.permission_object_id
FROM `category` c
inner join `category` parent on c.parent_catid = parent.catid and c.inherit_parent_perms='Y'
LEFT JOIN `permissions` p ON p.catid = parent.catid
WHERE c.catid = 5
) all_perms
WHERE (
        (
            (
                all_perms.permission_object_id = 'all'
                OR all_perms.permission_object_id = '100'
            )
                AND all_perms.permission_object = 'seller'
        )
        OR 
        (
            (
                all_perms.permission_object_id = 'all'
                OR all_perms.permission_object_id = '100'
            )
                AND all_perms.permission_object = 'buyer'
        )
    );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - 4 & 5 do have sub-categories but let me check it out and see if it works